# Radix-2^51 arithmetic of edwards25519

Tags: implementation, ed25519

The Golang implementation of edwards25519 (https://tip.golang.org/src/crypto/internal/edwards25519/field/fe.go) uses radix-2<sup>51</sup> representation. The description in section 3.2 in https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2660267.2660370, as well as the description in https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/ecc2013/files/peter_schwabe_1.pdf present the values of limbs: $a_0 = (2^{52} - 38)$, and $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, and $a_4 = (2^{52} - 2)$. I made sure I understand why $(2^{256} - 38) = (2^{52} - 38) + 2^{51} (2^{52}-2) + 2^{102} (2^{52}-2) + \ldots + 2^{204} (2^{52}-2)$. However, I could not figure out how one arrives at these values for the 5 limbs - especially $a_0 = (2^{52} - 38)$ and $a_1 = (2^{52} - 2)$, etc. I tried a few tricks with mod 51 arithmetic, nothing seems to lead me to these constants.

I'd really like to learn the basics that I'm clearly missing in this case.

Comment: [It is double of G.1.5. Curve25519](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-186.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the coefficients $a_i$ in the question starting from $a=2^{256}−38$ (that is twice the modulus $q=2^{255}-19$ that gives Ed25519 it's name)

- $t:=a$
- for $i$ from $0$ to $3$

  - $a_i:=t\bmod 2^{52}\quad$ (thus $0\le a_i<2^{52}$ by definition of $\bmod$ )
  - $t:=(v-a_i)/2^{51}\quad$ (the division is exact)
- $a_4:=t\quad$ (with $a_4=2\,\lfloor a/2^{205}\rfloor$ ).

For $i>0$, all the $a_i$ are even. $a_0$ is even iff $a$ is.

Another way to look at it is that

- $a_0$ is the integer formed by bits 0 to 51 of $a$
- $a_1$ is twice the integer formed by bits 52 to 102 of $a$
- $a_2$ is twice the integer formed by bits 103 to 153 of $a$
- $a_3$ is twice the integer formed by bits 154 to 204 of $a$
- $a_4$ is twice the integer formed by bits 205 and up of $a$

Radix $2^{51}$ for Ed25519 is exposed in [High-speed high-security signatures](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf#page=11) (Daniel J. Bernstein, Niels Duif, Tanja Lange, Peter Schwabe, Bo-Yin Yang, JoCE, 2012).

In a nutshell: this is base $2^{51}$, with digits allowed up to $2^{54}-1$. A benefit is that we seldom need to propagate carry in addition. Analogy in base 10: we can use digits in [0…79].

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!I could see a couple of places where I wasn't thinking clearly.